# C# Class Design - Events & long running methods

Tags: c#, events, background

I have a class that has some long running methods, in which they do DB queries, retrieve a list of objects, iterate through them and do some IO work.

How should this class design be approached?

Should I have `OnComplete` events in my class if the task completes?

I do want to give the consumer the ability to cancel/abort, so simply reporting when the method completes is not good enough.

Initially I had a `BackgroundWorker` (and much of the logic) in my UI code, however I separated the logic so it's all in a separate library.

I was considering adding the background worker in the class, and simply passing creating similar events as is raised by the background worker. Is this the best approach?

Comment: You might have to wait till Jon Skeet gets up for the bestest answer.

Comment: Jon Skeet can sleep in tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing inherintly wrong with using a background worker in your class. Probably what you are really looking for is the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx).